# How to change height of asp.net calendar control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net calendar that has these properties

```
 <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="250px"></asp:Calendar>
```

For some reason, I cannot change the height. I have tried different values, and it never changes how it looks in a browser. There must be a really simple answer to this, but I cannot find any possible problems and am getting overly frustrated... I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: use css [like here](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-Custom-Calendar-Control-using-CSS-styles.aspx)

Comment: Actually, thanks to that link, I see that the calendar uses tables. I've styled my tables to be a certain height... Learned something new. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should respect the height property ideally. However, any other styles on your page might be overriding this property.

Could you try checking the computed value for the height of the table that got emitted because of this calendar. In case no master page is being used and if it is not contained in any databound control, Calendar1 will be the id of the table tag that got emitted because of this asp control.

Between, I am using chrome for observing these styles.

Probably, this quick check can lessen your frustration by letting you know the culprit.

Comment: Yeah, figured this out... I was styling my tables and I had no clue this would affect a calendar. Thanks for the answer though, I will mark this as answer to close the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The minimum height is `Height="180px"` .

Comment: i took your code and paste it, i can change the height from 180px to what i want, it is working. maybe something else cause it?

Comment: I figured it out before thanks to @Wim Ombelets, I was styling my tables and this was affecting the calendar as well.